# Framework for CSS in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, css-frameworks

Which framework do you use in Rails 3.1?

I basically want to have a standard set of mixins like gradient and rounded corner etc, but maybe there are other advantages of certain frameworks that I am not aware of.

Can you please recommend a framework to use with Rails 3.1 to cover most of what I will need to simplify and standardize my stylesheet development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bourbon** -  a set of Sass mixins using SCSS syntax, is a popular (500+ watchers) tool made by **thoughtbot**.

The purpose of *Bourbon Sass Mixins* is to provide a comprehensive library of sass mixins that are designed to be as vanilla as possible, meaning they should not deter from the original CSS syntax. The mixins contain vendor specific prefixes for all CSS3 properties for support amongst modern browsers. The prefixes also ensure graceful degradation for older browsers that support only CSS3 prefixed properties. Bourbon uses SCSS syntax.

It can help with use:

- Animation
- Background-image
- Border Radius
- Box Shadow
- Box Sizing
  and other

See the readme on the official page [on github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon)

Answer (score 4):

I think that any current CSS framework can accomplish what you want.

Have you give [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) a look? I believe it meets all your criteria.

I haven't personally tried out [compass](http://compass-style.org/), but it's been generating alot of buzz, so it is certainly worth a look.

Twitter also released [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) which I've been trying out and I've been fairly impressed so far!

Answer (score 0):

For me, a framework doesn't seem to be to be considered here. You can easaly do it yourself.

For my part, I use sass and I write a **_macros.scss** with all the appropriate mixins and default variables, and I put an **@import "macros"**  at the beginning of each main scss files.

Comment: It does the work and I've no problem with this (and none with css).

Comment: Likewise, you might not have any problems with whatever car you drive, but that doesn't mean it's going to win any races. The power of Sass lies in being able to use intelligent structure and parsing to make writing CSS easier AND the output better. Frameworks give you a structure and a bunch of community tested code (which leads to better output). You're eschewing both blindly.

Comment: I agree and I don't want to reopen the war between pro's framework and con's. The fact is that once I used them for standard websites, but if you  something complicated, special to do, they are not appropriate. The fact is too that I love css (and  it is usefull when you build javascript applications).